# Why Google Measurement Protocol is splitting my session before the configured limit?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm working on a TV application and I would like to track what people do on it. So I used Google Measurement Protocole to do so. The page and event tracking is working fine because I can see in real time what's is happening on the Analytics 360 website. Everything was ok until I look at the "User explorer" to pick a random user in order to see what he did previously. I found out that he had a lot of sessions in a very short period. So I ran a test for myself yesterday and the result is the same today. I had only 1 session with multiple events for more than an hour and by paying attention to trigger an event before the 30min of inactivity which is configured by default.

Here are examples of data sent :

```
ds=qml
v=1
tid=UA-XXX-YYY
cd1=local
cm=tv
cid=123456789 (unique id)
uip=XX.XX.XX.XX
ua=SAMSUNG
ul=en
cd=HomePage
dp=HomePage
dt=home
cs=MY_TV_APP
t=event
ec=MY_TV_APP
ea=click on button
el=HomePage
```

or

```
ds=qml
v=1
tid=UA-XXX-YYY
cd1=local
cm=tv
cid=123456789 (unique id)
uip=XX.XX.XX.XX
ua=SAMSUNG
ul=en
cd=HomePage
dp=HomePage
dt=home
cs=MY_TV_APP
t=pageview
```

Here is a screenshot of my session: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BsqE.jpg)

As you can see, there are 7 sessions instead of 1... I don't understand why my session was splitted into 7 parts. I tried to use "**sc=start**" and "**sc=end**", the result is the same.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Comment: Your keeping cid the same for all the calls of the user after you do sc=start?  and your not calling sc=start again?

Comment: yes the cid is the same and calling sc=start only once or not calling it at all doesn't change anything.

Comment: did you ever manage to resolve this?